# SSLHandshakeException connecting to LDAP server in Notes

Tags: java, ssl, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have some java code that connects to an LDAP server via SSL:

```
protected DirContext getDirectoryContext(String usersDn, String password)
        throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    System.out.println("Connecting to LDAP.  Server=" + mURL + " User="
            + usersDn + " Password=" + password);

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, mURL);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, usersDn);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    if (mURL.startsWith("ldaps") || mURL.endsWith("636")) {
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
    }

    return new InitialDirContext(env);
}
```

The code is being run from a button on a Notes form in the Notes client V8.5.3.  The code is in a Java script libray.

Some people get a SSLHandshakeException No trusted certificate found,  while others do not get the excpetion and code runs fine.   The issue seems to be workstation related.

I do not get the error.  I have my own id which might have special access to the Notes server but I have a test id with no special access and both work from my PC.

I have a user that is also our ldap support so he should have everything he needs to connect to the server.   But the code gives him an exception.  Trying the Notes ldapsearch works fine from his PC so we know connectivity is good.

Error occurs for one user on both our Dev server and our QA server.  In Dev, I gave her the exact same access that I have.  Made he a developer and everything yet she still gets the exception.

So far the only people that the code has worked fine for are people in my group.  But as I mentioned I added the one woman to our group also I used a test ID that is not in our group that worked.   The only difference I can think of is that we all have designer and the others don't But I don't understand how that could be an issue.

And ideas why some people would get the error and others not?

Comment: check java versions, user key stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM got back to us with the fix.  Turns out the "other" users needed to import the cert.   They never answered why it worked for people with designer.   Perhaps a public cert gets installed when designer is installed that worked with our server.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the Lotus ldapsearch utility does not do SSL connections, so I believe the fact that it works is meaningless. I would take the error message at face value: the LDAP server's SSL certificate is either self-certified, or certified by a CA whose root certificate is not in the users' key store. Since this is Java running in a Notes button, I'm not quite sure what is used for the key store. I.e., I'm not sure if it's using a file in the JVM installed within Notes, or whether it's been wired up to use the local names.nsf. But being a Notes guy at heart, I'd look at the Certificates view in the client names.nsf on the machines where it works and on the machines where it doesn't.

Comment: Are you certain that ldapsearch does not connect SSL? I supplied the SSL port on my PC and it connect. Also it complained the first time I tried it. It said the SSL_SESSION_SIZE needed to be increased. But it was strange that if I set it to 0 then it still worked but did display a warning saying it needed to be increased.

Comment: How do I match up the actual certificate to what is in the PAB?  There seem to be no field names that are the same.  And why would the certificate be deleivered to some people and not others?

Comment: I have no recent certificates in my addressbook.  I backedup then deleted all of the certs from my addressbook and code still worked for me.   If it is indeed certificate related, it is not in the presonal addressbook.

Comment: AFAIK = As far as I know, ergo I'm not certain. There's no indication in the Domino Administrator doc for ldapsearch suggesting that it does use SSL if you specify the port, versus some other ldapsearch implementations that have special command line arguments for SSL. But perhaps if the key store in the Notes JVM is hard-wired into using the personal address book, so is the key store for ldapsearch in which case those special command line options are not needed.

Comment: Regarding the certificate, root certificates for SSL validation are similar to Notes PKI's concept of cross-certificates. (I'm assuming you're familiar with that.) The major CA's publish their roots, and software vendors build them into their products. The Internet Certificates in the personal NAB include a set that shipped with the template, plus ones that users have accepted. What you're looking for may not be something "recent". It may just be that the template version that the user's names.nsf was created from didn't have the root for whatever CA issued the LDAP server's certificate.

Comment: You could try a mass copy/paste from the personal names.nsf of a user that does not have the proble to the personal names.nsf of a user that does have the problem. If it doesn't fix the problem, then I'm wrong.  (Do a ctrl-shift-F9 in the target names.nsf after the paste and restart the client just to be sure. No idea if it's really needed.)